# Spring batch excel extension

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-excel

to read an excel file composed of 17 columns and a single line I used the excel extension Spring batch. the problem is that when I run the application, it gets to read the first 9 columns after this index I get an error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 9
at org.springframework.batch.item.excel.support.rowset.DefaultRowSet.getColumnValue(DefaultRowSet.java:71) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.demo.mappers.UtilisateurExcelRowMapper.mapRow(UtilisateurExcelRowMapper.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.demo.mappers.UtilisateurExcelRowMapper.mapRow(UtilisateurExcelRowMapper.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.batch.item.excel.AbstractExcelItemReader.doRead(AbstractExcelItemReader.java:70) ~[classes/:na]
... 50 common frames omitted
```

below my code

```
@Bean
PoiItemReader<Utilisateur> excelUtilisateurReader() {
    PoiItemReader<Utilisateur> reader = new PoiItemReader<Utilisateur>();
    reader.setLinesToSkip(5);
    reader.setMaxItemCount(1);
    reader.setRowMapper(excelRowMapper());
    return reader;
}
```

note that my file contains 17 columns all filled

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of `excelRowMapper()` ?

Comment: See Anish's answer ;)

Comment: Can you share the line that causes the issue? How can we reproduce the problem to be able to help you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the problem of [spring-batch-excel](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel) library.
For some reason, it does not take into account empty cells, e.g:
[image]
In `RowMapper` class, `RowSet` object for 3 and 4 rows will contain only 4 items (and you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`), but `RowSet` object for 5 row - 8 items.

I've fixed it by adding validation in `RowMapper`:

```
public class MyRowMapper implements RowMapper<MyDto> {

    @Override
    public MyDto mapRow(RowSet rowSet) throws Exception {
        MyDto dto = new MyDto();

        dto.setStart(checkAndGetCell(rowSet, 2));
        dto.setEnd(checkAndGetCell(rowSet, 3));
        dto.setStatus(checkAndGetCell(rowSet, 6));

        return dto;
    }

    private String checkAndGetCell(RowSet rowSet, Integer index) {
        return  rowSet.getProperties().size() > index ? rowSet.getColumnValue(index) : "";
    }
}
```